# Update Ionic 2 Platform

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app. If I change one piece of .ts code I had to perform the folowing steps:

- Remove platform;
- Ionic platform add android;
- Ionic run android or import gradle on android studio;

This process is very slow. How can automatically change .ts code without remove platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove and re-add, just do `ionic build android`.

In any case your workflow doesn't look right, why are you working with the built platform on android studio instead of just working with the files in your `app`directory?

Comment: why are you working with the built platform on android studio - do not understand

Comment: I assume you are removing and adding the platform because you are using android studio on the platform directory, for some reason. What's the function of android studio in your workflow? Why do you think you need to remove and add the platform every time you change a ts file?

Comment: I´m having a problem using ionic run android, but anyway I have a possiblity to sync gradle, but you gave the most important information. :)